# JsonConverter ClassNotFoundException in restlet

Tags: json, gwt, restlet, classnotfoundexception

I'm getting a server side `ClassNotFoundException` when calling restlet (2.1rc2) from GWT

> INFO: Unable to register the helper
>   org.restlet.client.ext.json.JsonConverter
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.restlet.client.ext.json.JsonConverter     at
>   org.restlet.engine.util.EngineClassLoader.findClass(EngineClassLoader.java:101)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)     at
>   org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelper(Engine.java:743)

I can't find `org.restlet.client.ext.json.JsonConverter` in any jar file and it doesn't appear in the javadocs on the restlet site so I'm at a bit of a loss what to do ?

Comment: thanks a lot for reporting this issue. I've updated the source code of both 2.1 and 2.2 branches.
The fix will be available in the 2.1.3 and 2.2m4 releases. Best regards,
Thierry Boileau

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error because I forget to import one dependency : ext.json dependency, the server side.

```
    <dependency>        
        <groupId>org.restlet.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.json</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>        
        <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.json</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

David.

Comment: My previous answer does not correct the problem.
I opened an issue for me because the jar is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

This class should be in the org.restlet.ext.json jar file. Have you this file in your classpath?

Thierry